# How do I extract the faces that are tagged in Lightroom using Metadata-Extractor?

Tags: java, metadata-extractor, lightroom

How do I extract the faces that are tagged in Lightroom using Metadata-Extractor?
All other data I easily find, but not all the faces. Am I doing something wrong, or does M-E lack support for this? If so, need help implementing it?

Comment: I'm not sure that I've added correct `lightroom` tag, but if I did - you should do it yourself next time as it looks like more `lightroom` than anything else oriented question.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, I'd suggest that Lightroom stores that data as XMP. You can use metadata-extractor to pull out XMP data, via the `XmpDirectory`.

If not, and it's stored elsewhere in the file, then I don't believe it is currently supported. You are most welcome to investigate adding support and sending in a PR. If you want to discuss the details of such a change first, please open an issue and attach a sample image that contains such metadata to that issue.